# The cout automatically goes to next line?

Tags: string, dictionary, iterator, cout

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string ,int > m;
    map <string ,int>::iterator it;
    char line[64];
    int t,n;

    m.clear();
    for(scanf("%d\n", &n); n--; )
    {
        fgets(line,64,stdin);
        line[32]=0;
        m[line]++;
    }
    for(it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first.c_str()<<it->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

The last line in this code after printing the `it->first.c_str()` automatically goes to the next line but I want to print the `it->second` in the same line.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: `fgets` leaves the newline character at the end of the line. In C++ it's more normal to use `getline` which doesn't have that behavior.

Comment: This seems more normal: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79667392c7fd3d66